# Работа с файлами в цикле bat

Tags: windows, строки, cmd, bat

У меня есть текстовый файл,он содержит строки,мне необходимо поменять местами четные и нечетные строки.Я взял четные и нечетные строки и выписал их в отдельные файлы.

```
@echo off 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "filepath1=C:\\Users\\andyb\\Desktop\\testfile.txt"
set "filepath2=C:\\Users\\andyb\\Desktop\\testfile2.txt"
set "filepath3=C:\\Users\\andyb\\Desktop\\testfile3.txt"
set counter=0
set B=0
for /F %%A in (%filepath1%) do (
set /a B=!counter!%%2
if !B! equ 0 (echo %%A>>%filepath2%) else (echo %%A>>%filepath3%)
set /A counter=counter+1
)
```

Теперь мне нужно брать одну строку из файла с нечетными строками,потом одну строку из файла с четными строками и записывать это в отдельный файл ,я никак не могу понять как в цикле это реализовать,так как переменной цикла присваивается одно значение из одного файла,а мне нужно за одну итерацию  взять по строке из двух файлов.

Comment: Почему бы не сделать все в одном шаге от исходного файла `testfile.txt`? Пожалуйста, [edit] свой запрос и добавьте пример ввода и вывода; необходимо следовать правила _[mcve]_.

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно использовать дополнительные файлы. Работайте с одним

```
@echo off 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set in_file=1.txt
set out_file=2.txt
rem //Строка, которая никогда не встретится в файле
set null="$$$$$"
rem //Предыдущая строка
set prev=%null%

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (%in_file%) do (
  if "!prev!" == "%null%" (
    rem //Если предыдущая строка пустая, то присваиваем текущую
    set prev=%%A
  ) else (
    rem //Иначе выводим текущую строку
    echo %%A>>%out_file%
    rem //выводим предыдущую строку
    echo !prev!>>%out_file%
    rem //Очищаем предыдущую строку
    set prev=%null%
  )
)   
rem //Если в файле нечетное количество строк, то выводим предыдущую строку
if not "!prev!" == "%null%" echo !prev!>>%out_file%
```